# How can I find shortest path with maximum number of yellow edges

Tags: algorithm, dijkstra

In given directed graph G=(V,E) , and weight function: w: E -> ℝ+ , such any vertex with color yellow or black, and vertex s.

How can I find shortest path with maximum number of yellow edges?

I thought to use Dijkstra algorithm and change the value of the yellow edges (by epsilon).. But I do not see how it is going to work ..

Comment: Could you elaborate on how the edge coloring works? Its unclear what you're asking

Comment: I edit the question. it's ok now?

Comment: To clarify - are you saying “pick, of all shortest paths, the one with the fewest number of yellow edges?”

Comment: not fewest, but *most* @templatetypedef

Comment: find the shortest and yellowest path

Comment: Suppose one path has length five and uses four yellow edges, and another has length six and uses five yellow edges. Which one would be preferred?

Comment: the shortest - length five. @templatetypedef

Comment: If the maximum number of yellow edges is equivalent to the minimal number of black edges, give the black edge a high cost so it is selected only if there is no yellow edge available.

Comment: @StudentOrint so it seems you want to return the shortest path anyways. Just if there are two different shortest paths return the one with more yellow edges? So if you have one path A with length 6 and 3 yellow edges, a path B with length 4 and 1 yellow edge and a path C with length 4 and 2 yellow edges you want C, right?

Comment: What do you have, yellow vertices or yellow edges?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Dijkstra shortest path algorithm, but add a new vector `Y` that has an element for each node that keeps track of the number of the yellow edges that it took so far until we get to that node.

Initially, set `Y[i] = 0` for each node i.

Also suppose `Yellow(u,v)` is a function that returns 1 if  `(u,v)` is yellow and 0 otherwise.

Normally, in the [Dijkstra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Pseudocode) algorithm you have:

```cpp
for each neighbor v of u still in Q:
         alt ← dist[u] + Graph.Edges(u, v)
         if alt < dist[v]:              
              dist[v] ← alt
              prev[v] ← u
```

You can now change this to:

```cpp
for each neighbor v of u still in Q:
         alt ← dist[u] + Graph.Edges(u, v)
         if alt < dist[v]:              
              dist[v] ← alt
              prev[v] ← u
              Y[v]← Y[u] + Yellow(u,v)          
         else if alt == dist[v] AND Y[u]+Yellow(u,v) > Y[v]:              
              prev[v] ← u
              Y[v]← Y[u] + Yellow(u,v)
```

**Explanation:**

In the else part that we added, the algorithm decides between alternative shortest paths (with identical costs, hence we have `if alt == dist[v]`) and picks the one that has more yellow edges.

Note that this will still find the shortest path in the graph. If there are multiple, it picks the one with higher number of yellow edges.

**Proof:**

Consider the set of visited nodes `Visited` at any point in the algorithm. Note that `Visited` is the set of nodes that are removed from `Q`.

We already know that for each `v ∈ Visited`, `dist[v]` is the shortest path from Dijkstra Algorithm's proof.

We now show that for each `v ∈ Visited`, `Y[v]` is maximum, and we do this by induction.

When `|Visited| = 1`, we have `Visited = {s}`, and `Y[s] = 0`.

Now suppose the claim holds for `|Visited| = k` for some `k >= 1`, we show that when we add a new node `u` to `Visited` and the size of `Visited` grows to `k+1`, the claim still holds.

Let `(t_i,u)` represent all edges from a node in `Visited` to the new node `u`, for which `(t_i,u)` is on a shortest path to `u`, i.e. `t_i ∈ Visited` and `(t_i,u)` is the last edge on the shortest path from `s` to `u`.

The else part of our algorithm guarantees that `Y[u]` is updated to the maximum value among all such shortest paths.

To see why, without loss of generality consider this image:

[image]

Suppose `s-t1-u` and `s-t2-u` are both shortest paths and the distance of `u` was updated first through `t1` and later through `t2`.

At the moment that we update `u` through `t2`, the distance of `u` doesn't change because `S-t1-u` and `S-t2-u` are both shortest paths. However in the else part of the algorithm, `Y[u]` will be updated to:

`Y[u] = Max (Y[t1] + Yellow(t1,u) , Y[t2] + Yellow(t2,u) )`

Also from the induction hypothesis, we know that `Y[t1]` and `Y[t2]` are already maximum. Hence `Y[u]` is maximum among both shortest paths from `s` to `u`.

Notice that for simplicity without loss of generality the image only shows two such paths, but the argument holds for all `(t_i,u)` edges.

Comment: Can you explain more please? how to choose this epsilon/constant ?

Comment: That might return a path that was not a shortest path, if it included fewer black edges.

Comment: @StudentOrint: I originally misunderstood the question. I now completely changed my solution.

Comment: You can explain how you can prove here the correctness that is really acheive the shortest and yellowest path? the shortest - because that is still like dijkstra, but the yellowest? @Ari

Comment: @StudentOrint: I added proof

Comment: @Sneftel: I revised the algorithm.